# How to select all text in TextBoxs using Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

In my WPF application I use Caliburn.Micro to bind between View and ViewModel.

In my View I have StackPanel with Text box

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="Ctx_A" />
    <TextBox x:Name="Ctx_B" />
    <TextBox x:Name="Ctx_C" />
    <TextBox x:Name="Ctx_D" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now I want to select all text after focus on TextBox. In my ViewModel I write method TextBoxGotFocus

```
public void TextBoxGotFocus(object sender)
{
  var tb = sender as TextBox;
  if (tb != null)
  {
    tb.SelectAll();
  }
}
```

Next I go back to my View and write something like that:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="Ctx_A" cal:Message.Attach=" [Event GotFocus]=[Action TextBoxGotFocus($source)]"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Ctx_B" cal:Message.Attach=" [Event GotFocus]=[Action TextBoxGotFocus($source)]"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Ctx_C" cal:Message.Attach=" [Event GotFocus]=[Action TextBoxGotFocus($source)]"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Ctx_D" cal:Message.Attach=" [Event GotFocus]=[Action TextBoxGotFocus($source)]"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there any possible to attach this method to StackPanel instead TextBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would remove the `TextBoxGotFocus()` method from your view model, because it's blurring the lines between your view and your view model. View models shouldn't be using any WPF controls in them. Instead, the easiest way I can think of to do this is to create a class that inherits from `TextBox`, and then attach an event to that:

```
public class AutofocusTextBox : TextBox
{
    public AutofocusTextBox()
    {
        GotFocus += (sender, e) => SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML, you can just use it like this:

```
<local:AutofocusTextBox ... />
```

That will keep your XAML a lot cleaner

Answer (score 0):

All Credit goes to Dr. WPF... [Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/564b5731-af8a-49bf-b297-6d179615819f/how-to-selectall-in-textbox-when-textbox-gets-focus-by-mouse-click?forum=wpf)

in the abcView.xaml

```
<TextBox    Text="{Binding Amount}" 
            MinWidth="100" 
            cal:Message.Attach="[Event GotFocus] = [Action GotFocusMethod($source)];
            [Event PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown] = [Action SelectivelyIgnoreMouseButton($source, $eventArgs)]" />
```

in the abcViewModel.cs

```
    // called by ui... used to highlight a textbox on focus
    public void GotFocusMethod(object source)
    {
        var based = source as TextBox;
        based.SelectAll();
    } // close gotfocusmethod

    // called by ui... used to highlight a textbox on focus
    public void SelectivelyIgnoreMouseButton(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs eve)
    {
        TextBox tb = (sender as TextBox);

        if (tb != null)
        {
            if (!tb.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
            {
                eve.Handled = true;

                tb.Focus();
            }
        }
    } // close selectivelyignoremousebutton()
```